# Centre aligned text with multi-cols and flowfram

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I know the question has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18036/center-align-text-in-columns-in-tabular-environment-in-multicol-environment), but I still can't get all the text within multi-cols to be centre aligned.

Here's what I have with the incorrect left-aligned text:

```
% document class
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

% stuff
\pagestyle{empty}         % no page numbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}     % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                   % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % figures
\usepackage{hyperref}           % hyper links
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Call colours by their svgnames
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}% bullet items
\usepackage{multicol} % Leelo Multi Cols


% Create column layout
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
  \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
  \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.22\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{2\columnsep}
% right frame
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]


% Start The Fans Please!
\begin{document}

\hspace*{\parindent}% text in specimen is set into page somewhat
\begin{minipage}[c]{5.1cm}% adjust to taste
\begin{center}


Barn water\\
boobtube shotgun\\
hayseed hootin'\\
creosote fricasee\\
Catfight spittin'\\
grandma everlastin'\\
Jail cousin\\
% end justify center
\end{center}\normalsize
\framebreak
\end{minipage}
% End of mini page

\hspace*{1em}% avoid text hitting edge of frame or background - adjust to taste
\vfill\vfill% adjust to taste or reduce to one \vfill if setting \vspace*{} to a specific value above

\framebreak% force following text to next flow frame

% Right frame

%Leelo multi pass
\begin{multicols}{3}
It's light.\\
Handle's adjustable\\
for easy carrying, good for righties and lefties. Breaks down into four parts, undetectable by x-ray, ideal for quick, discreet interventions. A word on firepower. Titanium recharger, three thousand round clip with bursts of three to three hundred, and with the Replay button - another Zorg invention - it's even easier.


% End multi cols No more multi pass
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The new example generates `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 \hspace*{1em}`

Comment: I would be amazed if flowfram and multicol are compatible (I'm not even sure what you want it to do? If I remove the lines that generate errors and remove `multicol` then the centering happens in the flowfram frames as I'd expect/

Comment: This is specifying a three column layout within the first frame which is only .24 of the textwidth so you only get about one word per column, is that what you intend? `\centering` can't really do much if there is only one word on each line.

Comment: That's right. The left column is just a list, which works with hard new lines. The document works, I just need to align the multi cols. I've updated the .tex file above.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what problem you had, but center alignment is obtained with `\centering`

[image]

```
% document class
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

% stuff
\pagestyle{empty}         % no page numbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}     % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                   % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % figures
\usepackage{hyperref}           % hyper links
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Call colours by their svgnames
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}% bullet items
\usepackage{multicol} % Leelo Multi Cols


% Create column layout
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
  \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
  \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.22\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{2\columnsep}
% right frame
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]


% Start The Fans Please!
\begin{document}

\hspace*{\parindent}% text in specimen is set into page somewhat
\begin{minipage}[c]{5.1cm}% adjust to taste
\begin{center}


Barn water\\
boobtube shotgun\\
hayseed hootin'\\
creosote fricasee\\
Catfight spittin'\\
grandma everlastin'\\
Jail cousin\\
% end justify center
\end{center}\normalsize
\framebreak
\end{minipage}
% End of mini page

\hspace*{1em}% avoid text hitting edge of frame or background - adjust to taste
\vfill\vfill% adjust to taste or reduce to one \vfill if setting \vspace*{} to a specific value above

\framebreak% force following text to next flow frame

% Right frame

%Leelo multi pass
\begin{multicols}{3}\centering
It's light.\\
Handle's adjustable\\
for easy carrying, good for righties and lefties. Breaks down into four parts, undetectable by x-ray, ideal for quick, discreet interventions. A word on firepower. Titanium recharger, three thousand round clip with bursts of three to three hundred, and with the Replay button - another Zorg invention - it's even easier.


% End multi cols No more multi pass
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked with my simplified example. However I realized I'm using two frames which is causing problems with \centering> I've updated the example.

Comment: @GhoulFool The answer hasn't changed but I updated the example and image to be based on your new flowfram example.